# Need to save twice with guard and livereload

Tags: guard, livereload

When I save changes to a html file, the browser refreshes the page quickly and correctly. The first time I save changes to a scss file, the page starts to reload, but stops without loading any of the style sheets (although it does load images). If I save it a second time, the page reloads fully. Thereafter, most I only need one save.  However, sometimes I have to do a second save in order to get it working properly again.

I am running `rails v4.2.5.1`, `guard v2.13.0`, `guard-livreload v2.5.1`, `chrome browser v48` with `livereload extensions 2.1.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when I upgraded by hard drive from a mechanical to a SSD drive, this problem stopped occuring. Maybe something was timing out.

Answer (score 0):

Best to open issues like that in guard-livereload. There are lots of moving parts here. And there are debugging options on both sides.

If an SSD drive fixed things, your editor may have had a lot of plugins activated during save - and if the "total save time" is longer for multiple files, things can get wacky. It could be lots of issues, so it's best to open an issue and ask for help. (There are debugging tutorials in Wikis too).